# Commutative von Neumann Algebras

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I am looking for a good reference for the theorem that shows that every commutative von Neumann algebra is $*-$ isomorphic to $L^{\infty}$.
Since I intend to grasp its proof perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Takesaki, Theory of Operator Algebras volume I, Theorem III.1.18.
- Murphy, C$^*$ Algebras and Operator Theory: Theorem 4.4.4
- Kadison Ringrose, Theorem 9.4.1 (although one needs to work a bit to obtain the exact statement in OP)
- Sakai, C$^*$ Algebras and W$^*$ Algebras, Theorem 1.18.1
- Dixmier, von Neumann Algebras: Theorem I.7.3.1
- Blackadar, Operator Algebras: Corollary III.1.5.18

Comment: Thanks, Merci , since Canada is bilingual.

Comment: "Bienvenue", but then I have already used most of my Québécois :D

Comment: If you don't mind https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3175203/what-does-the-statement-let-k-be-the-choquet-simplex-of-all-probability-measu