# What does the statement (Let $K$ be the choquet simplex of all probability measures on $X$) mean?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, operator-algebras, ergodic-theory

Let $X$ be a probability measure space.

What does the statement (Let $K$ be the choquet simplex of all probability measures on $X$) mean ?

It is mentioned in C. Lance. Ergodic Theorems for Convex Sets and Operator Algebras page 202 the second and third lines.
[image]

[image]

Comment: If $X$ is finite then the set of probability measures corresponds to a [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex) in the usual sense

Comment: Shouldn't it be "Let $X$ be a compact metric space"?  Is that a typo?

Comment: @Blackbird the set of all probability measures on $X$ is a weak* compact convex set and it is also metrisable.

Comment: @Neilhawking You didn't answer my question.  On the first line, you say that $X$ is a "probability measure space".  Did you instead mean to say that $X$ is a compact metric space?  The probability measures on a compact metric space form a Choquet simplex.

Comment: @blackbird $X$ is just a probability space.

Comment: @Neilhawking But what does it mean "all probability measures on a probability space"?  A probability space already has a probability measure.

Comment: @blackbird it means all probability measures that can be defined on the set $X$

Comment: @Neilhawking So $X$ is just a measurable space, not a probability space.

Comment: In any case, if $X$ is a compact metric space, then the probability measures on $X$ form a Choquet simplex (i.e., compact convex set $K$ in which every point is the center of mass of a probability measure on $K$ supported at the extremal points of $K$).  If $X$ is just measurable space, then it is not clear what topology you consider on the set of probability measures, and in particular what it means for it to be compact.

Comment: @Blackbird see the post again

Comment: I don't have the time to read the paper.  The theorem on the 1st page is in an abstract setting and does not refer to $X$.  I guess the mention of the Choquet simplex concerns an application of the theorem to a more concrete setting which will be dealt with in Section 2.  From the 1st paragraph on the 2nd page, it seems that in Section 2, $X$ will be a compact convex set in a locally convex space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mostly a name.

"Choquet" because of the analogy with the case where you consider the state space of a function system $K\subset C(X)$ for a compact Hausdorff space $X$ ($K$ is  a unital selfadjoint subspace). As the dual of $C(X)$ are the regular Borel measures, the state space of $K$ consists of the probability measures; and one calls it "simplex" because it is the closed span of its extreme points, namely the point measures.

When $X$ is just a set, you can still consider the probability measures, and still the extreme points will be the point measures. So "Choquet simplex". But you shouldn't read much on it.

Comment: If you don't mind https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3189877/alpha-and-alpha-in-c-algebra-and-von-neumann-algebra

Comment: The definition of a Choquet simplex is more specific than just "equal to the closed convex hull of its extreme points". Krein-Milman tells us that every compact convex subset of a LCTVS fits this description. But a Choquet simplex is more specific.

I want to emphasize that this is an *incorrect* definition of a Choquet simplex.

Answer (score 2):

In a fairly general setting (LCTVS), a point in a compact convex set K can be represented as the barycenter of a probability measure on the extreme points of K.  When K is a *Choquet simplex*, this representation is unique.  In the case at hand, the phrase draws attention to the fact that an invariant measure is canonically a direct integral of ergodic invariant measures.