# $\alpha^*$ and $\alpha_*$ in $C^*$ algebra and von Neumann algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

I have questions regarding part of [E. Christopher Lance. **Ergodic Theorems for Convex Sets and Operator Algebras**](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01390319), Page 202.

More precisely, in the paragraph starting with "We assume familiarity with..." the 7th line (the adjoint mapping $\alpha^*$) and the 10th line (automorphism $\alpha_*$).

I would like to know how $\alpha^*$ and $\alpha_*$ are defined.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is an automorphism of $\mathfrak{A}$, then
$$\alpha^*\colon S(\mathfrak{A})\to S(\mathfrak{A}),\qquad \alpha^*(\tau)=\tau\circ\alpha.$$

If $\mathfrak{A}$ is a von Neumann algebra, the predual $\mathfrak{A}_*$  is the space of ultraweakly continuous linear functionals on $\mathfrak{A}$. $\alpha_*$ is given similarly:
$$\alpha_*(f)=f\circ\alpha$$
It is stated that "$\alpha$ is the adjoint of $\alpha_*$". This is because a von Neumann algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ is canonically identified with the dual $(\mathfrak{A}_*)^*$, in which case $\alpha$ is really just the adjoint of $\alpha_*$ in the sense of Banach spaces.